# My async metho didn't go after "for" iteration

Tags: flutter, asynchronous

My code like this:

```
  Future<List<ListClass>> getIndexList() async {
    return Future.delayed(delayTime).then((_) async {
      //initialize
      List<ListClass> resultListItems = new List<ListClass>();
      await listCollection.get().then((value) async {
        var v = value.data;
        for (var data in v) {
          String userId = data['userId'];
          String authorName=await UserTable().getUserNameById(userId);
          print("createUserName=" + authorName);
          resultListItems.add(
              ListClass(header, content, userId, wordCount, authorName));
        }
        print("resultListItems.length="+resultListItems.length.toString());
        return resultListItems;
      });

     return resultListItems;
    });
  }
```

When I debug,it shows that this method return null,and after the `for`,the `print("resultListItems");` doesn't run too. How can I fix this?Thanks!!

Comment: first check is there any data in "var v = value.data;". If v contains data then your for will execute otherwise not.

Comment: print('userName'..) runs ok,the add method goes well,I can see into this list before the end of for clause.But it doesn't run the next one

Comment: do not use `then` (low level `Future` API) inside `async` method - instead just use `await` - it is much easier and save (especially if you are new to `async` stuff)

Comment: Sorry,without `then` how can I get the value?

Comment: `final foo = await listCollection.get(); print(foo);`

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem,the for clause doesn't run completely.One of my data in database is null,so it runs with bug.Sorry for my fault